# Accessing distant database, android

Tags: database, android

I'd like to access an Internet database from my app to edit it and read it. Any link I should read or any advise?

Thanks

Comment: Can you expand on "internet database"? Is it an SQL server listening to the world? Is it a web service backed by database? Is it a CSV file on an FTP site?

Answer (score 1):

You should offer API to  operate the database as a server. Then your app can call them with HTTP way.